# Javascript try catch statement

Tags: javascript, html

I'm analyzing some code on a website and I came across the following anonymous function followed by a try catch statement. I'm just wondering what the try catch statement is doing at the end there. Is it pre-loading the url so thats it loads more quickly then the anonymous function goes? Also, whats the point is it's not catching any errors.

```
(function() {
        var fired = false;
        bsnPop.add("http://www.someurl.com", {
            under: !noPopunder,
            newTab: false,
            forceUnder: true,
            shouldFire: function() {
                return !fired;
            },
            cookieExpires: -1,
            afterOpen: function(url) {
                createCookie();
                fired = true;
                doSecondPop();
            }
        });
    })();
    try {
        var hint = document.createElement("link");
        hint.rel = "dns-prefetch";
        hint.href = "http://www.someurl.com";
        document.head.appendChild(hint);
        var hint = document.createElement("link");
        hint.rel = "preconnect";
        hint.href = "http://www.someurl.com";
        document.head.appendChild(hint);
    } catch (e) {}
```

Comment: Pretty useless...

Comment: Your title suggests you're asking a question about the `try`/`catch` feature of JavaScript, but you're not; the question is asking what the **code *inside* the `try`** is doing. That's completely unrelated to `try`/`catch`. Separately: *"whats the point is it's not catching any errors."* Yes, it catches all errors. It then completely ignores them.

Comment: Only effect seems to be to suppress console errors

Comment: It allows to continue the execution even if an error occurs. Then you could deal with this error in the catch statement and the program will not break

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to the [link types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) list on MDN, "dns-prefetch" and "preconnect" are listed as experimental. They do not appear in the list of "rel" values for link types of link elements in [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes)

So the code is using experimental technology on the web which might throw an error in some browsers. To prevent stopping the application and logging an exception on the console, the code is placed in a `try` block with a `catch` block that ignores the error.

---

In answer to question details, the anonymous function in the IIFE is invoked and  passes an object containing parameters and callbacks in a call to `bsnPop.add`. It does not appear to create a popup window at this stage.

Next code within the `try` block attempts to speed up access to the web site by requesting DNS lookup of the website's name in advance, and to open a connection to the site before attempting to retrieve content.

The code is placed in the `try` block to accommodate the possibility of a browser throwing an exception if the requested operations are not supported. The application does not consider lack of support an error and wants to continue anyway.

The end result is that if `dns-prefetch` or `preconnect` are supported the browser can take the hint and perform the operations. If they are not supported any error generated is ignored and code continues at the next statement - connecting to the website later will have to proceed at normal speed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the anonymous functions fires then the try catch also fires? I don't understand the point if both are essentially doing the same thing. Whats the point?

Comment: @EliseCrane , I've updated the answer in response to your comment.